# Android NDK. Loading ETC1 compressed texture from .PVR file

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

Since PVR file format and PVRTexTool utility supports ETC compression -- I want to use it for my textures in the Android project.

Unfortunately I found no libs or samples how to load ETC1 OpenGL texture from PVR file.

One source I have is Objective-C PVR loader for iOS. But I need some example on C++ for Android NDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much info on this out there, however there are a couple of things. [http://www.brokenteapotstudios.com/android-game-development-blog/2011/05/loading-opengl-textures-in-c-and-etc1-texture-compression.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20150323224427/http://www.brokenteapotstudios.com/android-game-development-blog/2011/05/loading-opengl-textures-in-c-and-etc1-texture-compression.html) provides most of the info needed. If you want to use the header version, the header format is described here http://www.mhgames.org/2012/03/android-development-loading-etc1-textures-from-ndk/

Hopefully that's helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Read this first regarding compressed textures on android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html (scroll down to the "OpenGL Versions and Device Compatibility" chapter)

There's also the ETC1Util class (as referred from the link above) :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/ETC1Util.html

Logical thing to do would be to use `ETC1Util.isETC1Supported()` to see if ETC1 is supported on your device and if not, provide a fallback option.

I also recommend you take a look (if you haven't done so already) at the PowerVR android sdk:
http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp
I haven't taken a look at it myself, but I'm sure it's got what you are looking for.

So, I don't think there's any need for Objective-C...

Good luck!